# I try pull a remote branch. Error: fatal: cannot lock ref

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I try:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b events_add_place origin/events_add_place
```

And I get en error:

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/events_add_place': 'refs/heads/events_add_place/master' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/events_add_place'
```

I try:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Not help

Comment: `git checkout -b events_add_place origin/events_add_placeA` tries to create a 
new branch `events_add_place` from `origin/events_add_placeA`. The error means that `events_add_place` has already existed.

Comment: @ElpieKay How I can switch a remote branch otherwise?

Comment: @AlexReuka You already have a branch `events_add_place/master` so you cannot have `events_add_place`. Remove or rename `events_add_place/master`; or use other name, not `events_add_place`. Use `events_add_place/A`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall IDE, I use:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b events_add_place origin/events_add_place
```

End it work. I switched a new branch.